# How to get the product title name in the product image model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How do i access the title field in the product image model so i can upload to specific folder in the media.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('T-Shirt', 'T Shirt'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    bestselling = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/' + str(product.))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

Comment: you can get the foreign key field data within an instance of ProductImage. product_image_instance = ProductImage .objects.get(id=?) 
 `product_image_instance.product.title`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do i pass that back into the model

Comment: what do you mean by `pass that back into the model` ? you can write a custom model method to return product title and call it in the ProductImage instance